# Solve in integers: $x^2 = y^2 + y + 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Solve this equation in integers: 
$$x^2 = y^2 + y + 1$$
I know $2$ ways to solve this. But they are not easy. Maybe there is some quick method.

Comment: Could you give at least an outline of those two ways that you know to solve the equation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$x^2 = y^2 + y + 1$

$4x^2 = 4y^2 + 4y + 4$

$(2x)^2 = (2y + 1)^2 + 3$

The only squares that differ by 3 are 1 and 4.

So $2x = \pm 2$, and $2y + 1 = \pm 1$

i.e. $x = -1,1$, $y = -1,0$

Answer (score 3):

$$x^2 = y^2 + y +1$$
$$x^2-1=y^2+y$$

Immediately we see that $x=\pm1,y=-1$

Alternatively $x=\pm1, y=0$

---

**How can we tell there are no more solutions?**

As Neil has said:$$x^2 = y^2 + y +1$$ $$4x^2=4y^2 + 4y + 4$$
$$(2x)^2=(2y+1)^2+3$$

**What squares differ by only $3$?**

$1^2=1,2^2=4,3^2=9,4^2=16,5^2=25,6^2=36$

We can see that the numbers increase by $3,5,7,9,11,\dots$

Hence $x^2=1,4$ are the only squares that differ by three.

---

This is because $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$

Hence $(x+1)^2-x^2=3$, has solutions:

$$2x+1=3\implies x=1$$

and $x^2-(x+1)^2=3$, has solutions:
$$-2x-1=3$$$$-2x=4\implies x=-2$$

So the only squares that differ by $3$ are $x^2=1,4$

---

$$(2x)^2=(2y+1)^2+3$$
$2x = \pm 2$ and $2y + 1 = \pm 1$

Hence $(x,y)=(\pm1,0)$ or $(\pm1,-1)$

Comment: Thanks nice, but how to prove that there are no more solutions.

Comment: Your logic for showing there are no other solutions is flawed. By that logic the Pythagorean equation $a^2=b^2+c^2$ can be considered as $a^2=b^2$ and $c^2=0$ which obviously will lead to only a subset of the actual solutions.

Comment: @Macavity Perhaps I am completely wrong though, so I will think about it and edit this post later and ask you for confirmation(if you don't mind of course)

Comment: Sure, will wait. Another way to note the flaw is to see that in real numbers, you will have other solutions, but your method does not allow those either. It boils down to $a+b=x+y$ does not imply $a=x$ and $b=y$, though the reverse implication is correct.

Comment: @Macavity I can't delete because it is the accepted answer(Although Neil has the better answer). Thank you for your comments.

Comment: That's fine, just edit and correct the answer, you'll probably get the up votes too.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Other than $y\in \{0, -1\}$ we have $x^2$ between $y^2$ and $(y+1)^2$.